# Specify OAuth token in GET URL

Tags: rest, oauth, get, oauth-2.0, bearer-token

My REST service uses OAuth 2.0 authentication. I want to test some GET URLs using the browser (without using a client). Can I pass the bearer token in the URL ?
URL : www.example.com/employee/employeeId

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it in the `access_token` query parameter, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.3, but as noted in the other answer, it is not the preferred way of passing a token. It may end up in logs, browser cache etc. On this method the spec says:

> Because of the security weaknesses associated with the URI method
> (see Section 5), including the high likelihood that the URL
> containing the access token will be logged, it SHOULD NOT be used
> unless it is impossible to transport the access token in the
> "Authorization" request header field or the HTTP request entity-body.
> Resource servers MAY support this method.
>
> This method is included to document current use; its use is not
> recommended, due to its security deficiencies (see Section 5) and
> also because it uses a reserved query parameter name, which is
> counter to URI namespace best practices, per "Architecture of the
> World Wide Web, Volume One" [W3C.REC-webarch-20041215].

So you should also be aware that the Resource Server (or API) may not even support this method of token passing. The only method that is mandatory to implement is the Authorization header method.

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly can.

Ses facebook graph [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens). But be aware that it is not recommended since users may sent these urls as email or messages. Oauth 2.0 spec writes about it.